# Sqlite very slow on for loop delete

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this local db that I'm playing with and it pulls a list of users, does something with each and then deletes the records. The delete is VERY slow:

```
    db.all("select id, username from users", (err, rows) => {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            // do stuff with row
            db.run("delete from users where id = ?", row.id, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

It is a simple db: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text NOT NULL)`

Deleting a record takes even 20 seconds on a list of 100k records. What am I doing wrong here and how can I speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting a record takes even 20 seconds on a list of 100k records. What am I doing wrong here and how can I speed this up?

`db.all` will fetch *all* the rows at once. This is slow, consumes a lot of memory, and all rows must be fetched before any processing starts.

Instead, use [`db.each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite#each). This will fetch a row and act on it immediately.

There's also no need to use `where in (?)`. For a single value use `where = ?`. This may or may not affect performance.

```
db.each(
  "select id, username from users", (err, row) => {
    // do stuff with row

    db.run("delete from users where id = ?", row.id, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I do not want to delete all rows. I want to delete only what was looped/processed. If the program restarts I should pick it with the remaining items.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Since there's no `where` clause on the `select`, your code will, eventually, delete all rows. I'm not sure what the distinction you're making is. Can you provide an example where there would be a difference?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I'm guessing your code example skipped the "do something with the user" step before deleting.

Comment: exactly - I simplified it by removing the bits that are not relevant.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I see now. I mistook `// do stuff with row` to be a comment on the delete query. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Still stays about 20-30 seconds to delete. That `in` bit was a leftover from me trying to bulk delete (same result). I'll edit my code.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea It's 100k records, so yes, it will take a bit to process them all. Now it's doing it without consuming a ton of memory. Queuing up the IDs to delete and doing them about 1000 at a time with `in` would speed things up. Without seeing the rest of the code I can't say more.